# Docker Create react app hot reload not working

Tags: reactjs, windows, docker

I'm trying to set a development environment in Docker with Create React App and Node js.
but when I'm changing my code,it doesn't reload changes

Normally just using volumes would be enough, but I added also :
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
in ENV as create react app official documentation says, and I moved my code to WSL since I'm on Windows 10 but still the same.
I created a another project with create react app and I used docker with CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true and works just fine, but when I added more services won't work anymore.

#### this is my docker-compose file.

```
version: '3.3'
services:
  backend:
    image: node
    build:
      context: ./salesbackend/
    ports: 
      - 5000:3001
    env_file: ./salesbackend/.env
    volumes:
      - ./salesbackend:/var/app/salesbackend
      - /var/app/salesbackend/node_modules
    depends_on: 
      - mongo
  frontstore:
    build:
      context: ./frontstore/
    ports:
      - 5001:3000
      - 5002:3003
    env_file: ./frontstore/.env
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    volumes: 
      - ./frontstore:/var/app/frontstore
      - /var/app/frontstore/node_modules
    depends_on: 
      - backend
  frontend:
    build:
      context: ./frontend/
    ports:
      - 5003:4000
    env_file: ./frontend/.env
    environment:
      - NODE_ENV=development
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
    volumes: 
      - ./frontend:/var/app/frontend
      - /var/app/frontend/node_modules

  mongo:
    image: mongo
    volumes: 
      - ./db/:/data/db
    ports:
      - 30000:27017
```

#### This is my Dockerfile for frontend service,

-> Frontend and Frontstore are both made in create react app and both aren't working.

```
FROM node:10
WORKDIR /var/app/
COPY package.json /var/app/package.json
RUN npm install

COPY . .

CMD ["npm","start"]
```

using docker-compose up works just fine, when I edit my backend that is build in NestJS, changes auto reloads, but for create-react-app not.

Comment: This worked for me https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-create-react-app-in-docker-container/#Hot-Reloading-not-working

Answer (score 18, accepted):

### Fixed

This issue was 
in file **Dockerfile**
The workdir was `/var/app/`
while in my **docker-compose.yml** I mounted current working directory to `/var/app/frontend`, I just removed that */frontend* and works fine.

Answer (score -1):

The marked correct answer is not going to solve this problem for EVERYONE. because simply the questioner fixes it in his own way in the Dockerfile to install the node module on this container use extra work.

The problem is the docker bind mount setting is wrong. which is why the jetpack reacts node module for not reload is not loading on the docker container.

":" means bind mount

without ":" is simply nonsense.

volumes:

```
  - ./frontstore:/var/app/frontstore (this is correct)

  - /var/app/frontstore/node_modules (I don't know what is the point of this, this is not bind mount, this line have no meaning. )  

  - ./youtbackendfolder/node_modules:/yourappfolder/node_modules (this will make hot reload work) don't forget rebuild image and container
```

Comment: The marked answer works because it fixes the problem. Volumes without a ":" are specified in the version 3 docker-compose spec as "Just specify a path and let the Engine create a volume". You can find the documentation here: https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/compose-file-v3/#short-syntax-3