# Docker with create react app is not updating changes

Tags: node.js, reactjs, docker, docker-compose, wsl-2

I'm creating a React app with docker in WSL2 and create-react-app and everything seems to be working fine except the app is not updating with changes in the code. I mean, when I make a change in the code, the browser should update the changes automatically, but it doesn't and I have to restart the container to see them. I added `CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true` in `ENV` but it's not working either. These are the configuration files:

*dockerfile*

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:16.13.1

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies

COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

*docker-compose.yml*

```
services:
  react:
    build: ./frontend
    command: npm start
    ports:
      - 3000:3000
    volumes: 
      - ./frontend:/app
    env_file:
      - 'env.react'
```

*env.react*

```
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

*package.json*

```
{
  "name": "app",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@testing-library/jest-dom": "^5.16.1",
    "@testing-library/react": "^12.1.2",
    "@testing-library/user-event": "^13.5.0",
    "mdbreact": "^5.2.0",
    "react": "^17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "^17.0.2",
    "react-painter": "^0.4.0",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.1",
    "react-scripts": "5.0.0",
    "sass": "^1.45.1",
    "web-vitals": "^2.1.2"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "start": "react-scripts start",
    "build": "react-scripts build",
    "test": "react-scripts test",
    "eject": "react-scripts eject"
  },
  "eslintConfig": {
    "extends": [
      "react-app",
      "react-app/jest"
    ]
  },
  "browserslist": {
    "production": [
      ">0.2%",
      "not dead",
      "not op_mini all"
    ],
    "development": [
      "last 1 chrome version",
      "last 1 firefox version",
      "last 1 safari version"
    ]
  }
}
```

Can you see what I'm doing wrong? Thanks!

Comment: "except the app is not updating with changes" What do you mean by that. What changes, made where? How should app change to what action.

Comment: I mean, when I make a change in the code, the browser should update the changes automatically, but it doesn't . I think it's called hot reload.

Comment: I'm not quite sure if that is possible with containers. I know its possible for example when you're dealing with java and IntelliJ and youre having the servers run locally. But i have never seen anyone make it work when a container technology is used. As far as i see you are trying it with a volume, but as soon as you rebuild, the application file gets probably refreshed locally but the volume is still the same.

Comment: spa hot-reload features is for development stage not for production stage. Share us the package.json

Comment: I generally directly use Node for this sort of development, instead of trying to convince Docker that it wants to escape its normal filesystem isolation.  This setup isn't really using any of Docker's capabilities (you don't have an immutable reproducible image, the front-end application can't use Docker networking) and it's not clear what benefit you get from Docker here.

Comment: I've seen someone managed to use it with Docker: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58508772/docker-create-react-app-hot-reload-not-working; and I, myself, could do it in another project, but not anymore. I can't see the differences.  @JRichardsz, I added the package.json.

Comment: As David said, almost all the react developers use a simply nodejs, some ide (visual code, atom, sublime,etc) to get the hot reload feature which is: App restart on any change. Until windows os is enough. Docker is not for that. Why do you need docker for hot reload? Do you have a misconfigured windows environment in which you cannot install anything? Anyway magic don't exist but programming exist. Do you need to enable the hot reload for developer with docker or do you want to deploy your react app with docker for real users(main docker goal)?

Comment: As you recommended, I started using node.js instead of Docker and hot reload is not working either!!! I'm using WSL 2, could be that the problem?

Comment: I tried this: https://github.com/facebook/create-react-app/issues/10253#issuecomment-748433681, but it's not working either

Comment: Ok, the problem is with WSL2, as it's said in this answer https://github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6255#issuecomment-730701001: "If it is in the Windows file system, I believe you're running into the fact that the Plan 9 server in WSL 2 does not support file watching on Windows files. As a workaround I'd recommend you place your files into the Linux file system". I moved the files to /ubuntu/home/user and now the reload is working fine

Comment: This worked for me https://frontendguruji.com/blog/how-to-create-react-app-in-docker-container/#Hot-Reloading-not-working

Answer (score 29, accepted):

`CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING` will no longer work in `react-scripts` ^5, as Webpack started using its own filesystem watcher (*Watchpack*) as a replacement for *Chokidar*, try:

```yaml
environment:
  - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
```

Comment: It's also no working on Ubuntu 20.04 (but your fix worked - thanks!)

Comment: Sorry, I came back some years later... It is still not working for me, could you share your Dockerfile?

Comment: Oh, nothing, one minute after writing it is working... :D

Answer (score 1):

The problem is with WSL2, as it's said in this answer [www.github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6255#issuecomment-730701001](http://www.github.com/microsoft/WSL/issues/6255#issuecomment-730701001): "If it is in the Windows file system, I believe you're running into the fact that the Plan 9 server in WSL 2 does not support file watching on Windows files. As a workaround I'd recommend you place your files into the Linux file system". I moved the files to \\wsl$\Ubuntu\home\user and now the reload is working fine. I also stopped using Docker with React and now I directly use Node, as recommended in the comments.

**Note that I was having the same issue with Node alone, with files outside the Linux file system.**

Answer (score 1):

Add this enviroment variable:

```
environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

Comment: I already tried that without success, as mentioned in the question statement.

Comment: Not an answer but a workaround. You can use VSCODE to attach to a remote container. In other words it attaches to the React App you're working on. So, it refreshes with every change like normal. Here's instructions: https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/remote/attach-container.

Answer (score 0):

I'm using ubuntu:22.04 but I dont know why in Docker the live react-app update doesn't work for me while running the container .....In stackoverflow i found CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING but this also don't work any more.

Instead of that you can just add `-e WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` in your docker run command ...and that worked for me.

Answer (score 0):

**Note:** use cmd terminal instead of git-bash

For mounting volume on windows following command not working for **GIT-bash** but works fine on **cmd terminal**

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 --name react-container -v %cd%/src:/app/src -e CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true react-img
```

Answer (score -1):

`CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true`  is  not try
it  should be like

```
CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING: 'true'
```

Comment: CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true is the right yml syntax in the docker compose file

Comment: You are mistaked I have the true syntax  because  i have docker  and  i wrote it