# React JS doesn't update in Docker compose

Tags: reactjs, docker, docker-compose, dockerfile, client

First of all, I am really new to dockers and everything that relates to it. I tried to use tutorials and instructions from web, but I see the answers from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70488471/docker-with-create-react-app-is-not-updating-changes) and I guess I don't have other options other than move to Linux completely (which I really don't want to do)

I have a docker-compose project with ASP.NET Core, Nginx and React. FrontEnd and BackEnd have their own dockerfile and dockerignore.

FrontEnd doesn't update code changes at all.

I tried to build only client service by using `docker-compose build --no-cache` but after two minutes of compiling I see that it didn't change anything.

Only possible solution for me is to delete docker-compose project and compile every service again. But it makes development so much difficult.

dockerfile:

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY ./package.json /app
RUN npm install

COPY . .

RUN npm run build
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml (client service):

```
  client:
    image: client
    build:
      context: ./walletfrontend
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    environment:
      - WATCHPACK_POLLING=true
```

I tried to use `WATCHPACK_POLLING=true` as suggested in another question but I think it does nothing and I am not really sure why is it needed for.

**UPDATE:**

So I think I found a solution in this article:
https://shahmirprogrammer.medium.com/docker-with-react-changes-reflect-real-time-inside-a-container-f83acf208f8a

It really updates the changes in real time.

So my next goal is to change this strange command which I don't have a clue what it does to docker-compose equivalent:) :

```
docker run -d -p 3000:3000 -v /app/node_modules -v $(pwd):/app --name dockerized-react-app react-app-image:1
```

**UPDATE #2:**

So I think solution is to use volumes with correct path to my host machine:

```
volumes:
  - /app/node_modules
  - ./walletfrontend:/app
```

It's been almost a week and it was really difficult to find a solution for this. I hope this would help in the future for newbies like me

Answer (score 0):

```
FROM node:16-alpine

WORKDIR /app

ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

COPY ./package.json /app
COPY . .
RUN npm install

RUN npm run build
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

copy all the files before you run `npm install`.

a really useful tutorial on this can be found here

https://mherman.org/blog/dockerizing-a-react-app/

Dockerfile

```
# pull official base image
FROM node:13.12.0-alpine

# set working directory
WORKDIR /app

# add `/app/node_modules/.bin` to $PATH
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH

# install app dependencies
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm install --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts@3.4.1 -g --silent

# add app
COPY . ./

# start app
CMD ["npm", "start"]
```

docker-compose.yml

```
version: '3.7'

services:

  sample:
    container_name: sample
    build:
      context: .
      dockerfile: Dockerfile
    volumes:
      - '.:/app'
      - '/app/node_modules'
    ports:
      - 3001:3000
    environment:
      - CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING=true
```

that guide I just linked you also contains info on how to get your app production ready

Comment: doesn't work :(

Comment: if you want hot reload you need to map the volumes, see the docker-compose example I provided you with and update accordingly

Comment: I tried to do this way but there have been some other strange problems. I think I found a different solution, which I think you suggested already here: https://shahmirprogrammer.medium.com/docker-with-react-changes-reflect-real-time-inside-a-container-f83acf208f8a .